# Electron new app structure

Tags: javascript, electron

We're trying to create an app to track some logfiles and push those data to our API for our company. It'll be working on Mac OSX and Windows

So, we're really newbie at Electron. I just wonder there is a accepted file structure or framework for Electron ? Because, I don't want to mess up my codes in the future.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the features you want (angular, react, webpack, etc.), there are starter projects out there. Just have a look on Github for [electron starters](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=electron%20starter&type=Repositories). However, most projects follow a very similar structure, having at least the following directories:

- config
- app (or src)

  - component 1
  - component 2
- assets

  - fonts
  - images
- test

You may also search for *electron prebuilt*, *electron boilerplate* or *electron seed*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any boilerplate in the web.

see if this fit your needs:
https://github.com/szwacz/electron-boilerplate

Comment: +1 Can recommend. This boilerplate is framework agnostic, you can start writing ES7 from the start, you have working examples of unit and E2E tests, 3 common features have been solved for you (copy paste, external links, window sizing), can immediately be compiled into DMG and EXE.